# Refresh links with VBA doesn't find the source file when source file is being autosaved

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that when opened runs a macro that opens a different worksheet to update data and refresh the tables in it.

The issue is when, that first worksheet is opened to refresh and that coincides with the process of saving the second worksheet, the first worksheet doesn't find the second. Would there be any solution to override that?

```vb
Sub get_data()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Support").Select
Range("A2:BS1500").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Sheets("Run Rates").Select
Range("A2:BS1500").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Sheets("Graphs").Select
Range("A2:BS1500").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("X:\second worksheet.xlsm")
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("X:\first worksheet.xlsm")
'---------
Wb1.Sheets("Support").Range("A1:BS1500").Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Wb2.Sheets("SupportData").Select
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'---------
Wb1.Sheets("Run Rates").Range("A1:BS1500").Copy
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Wb2.Sheets("Run RatesData").Select
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'---------
Wb1.Sheets("Graphs").Range("A1:BS1500").Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Wb2.Sheets("GraphsData").Select
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("Support").Select
    Range("Table_Table2__3[[#Headers],[Date From]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Sheets("Run Rates").Select
    Range("Table_Table6[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Sheets("Graphs").Select
    Range("Table_Table8[[#Headers],[Column19]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets("Support").Select
 
End Sub
```

All files are on a company network

- first worksheet is used as "middle man" with tables to update a front end Dashboard.
- second worksheet is the actual main dashboard with all the information for the front end. This one is always opened on a different computer and is on autosave every 5 minutes.

I am trying for the front end worksheet, every x minutes to open the "middle man", update all the tables, save and close.

Comment: You have a typo on the Set wb lines:
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("X:"second worksheet.xlsm") - extra quotation, which I assume should be \ ? 

Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("X:\first worksheet.xlsm")

Comment: Yes, I have corrected that. Thanks, but that was just a typo on the code here.

Comment: Understood. Do you mean the second worksheet wb2 is not detected by wb1, or one of the sheets within these workbooks?

Comment: Wb1 is not detected by Wb2 when Wb1 is in the process of saving. All works fine apart the specific time when Wb1 is saving

Comment: I was wondering if "On Error Resume Next" will work, but not sure where in the code i should put it

Comment: How does Wb1 not being detected affect the result? It seems to me Wb2 has everything copied over already when Wb1 is saving?

Comment: It returns an error on "set Wb1 = ...." and the macro stops

Comment: Have you input the entire file path? Something like "X:\Users\luis\Documents\Workbook1.xlsm". The root of our problem seems to be with the file path used or with the location of the file. Is it just in the X drive on it's own? Right click the file click on properties, and copy the location

Comment: Yes, the location is correct.  And works ok most of the time. I think the issue is to do with, when the Wb1 file is saving it creates a temporary file and looks like it disappears for a moment. Maybe is just bad timing :)

Comment: Oh ok so it works most of the time, then this is a bit odd. Reading the code though, I don't see where Wb1 saves? I see it close but savechanges = False

Comment: Wb1 is always open on a different computer and is on autosave. This code opens Wb1 in read only

Comment: ok so you the issue occurs when Wb1 autosaves, and this code is attempting to access? In that case you have two options: turn off autosave and use this code to save wb1 instead, so you always have access; OR use an on error to skip the current instance of updating, or wait x time and try again. Whichever works best for you

Comment: Thanks, Alexander, I will try with "on error" as the other option can't use.

Answer (score 0):

After our clarification that the wb1 is not being detected due to its autosave schedule, this is how I would use OnError to skip the error. It sends the code to the ErrorHandler, which you can add anything you need to do before exiting the sub.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("X:\second worksheet.xlsm")
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("X:\first worksheet.xlsm")
'---------
On Error GoTo 0 
' Disables the errorHandler once passing the workbook detection, in case 
' something else does not work it will not simply exit the sub but show an error (optional)

Wb1.Sheets("Support").Range("A1:BS1500").Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Wb2.Sheets("SupportData").Select
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'---------
Wb1.Sheets("Run Rates").Range("A1:BS1500").Copy
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Wb2.Sheets("Run RatesData").Select
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'---------
Wb1.Sheets("Graphs").Range("A1:BS1500").Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Wb2.Sheets("GraphsData").Select
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("Support").Select
    Range("Table_Table2__3[[#Headers],[Date From]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Sheets("Run Rates").Select
    Range("Table_Table6[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Sheets("Graphs").Select
    Range("Table_Table8[[#Headers],[Column19]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Sheets("Support").Select

Exit Sub ' To avoid errorHandler if all ok
ErrorHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Revert to original settings

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks one more time Alexander, I will try your solution and leave it running for a couple of hours to see what happens.